# Error when accessing a member of a globally defined array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, global-variables, arkit

I am quite new to swift. I am attempting to define a global array of type `[String]` and then access the array for navigation through subscripts via `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, which are then fed into `loadedContentForAsset(name: String)` to display a `.scn` model. I have included the code for the global definition; I am getting a `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1049d69c8)` signal when executing the code.. on the last line of the included.

Here is my global definition:

```
    import Foundation

class Main {
    let faceOverlayArray: [String]
    init(faceOverlayArray:[String]) {
    self.faceOverlayArray = ["overlayModelBlack", "overlayModelBlue", "overlayModelRed", "overlayModelGreen", "overlayModelWhite"]
    }
}
let faceOverlayArray1 = (faceOverlayArray: ["overlayModelBlack", "overlayModelBlue", "overlayModelRed", "overlayModelGreen", "overlayModelWhite"]) as! [String]
```

Any suggestions or pointers are greatly appreciated!

---

Here modified code that works:

```
`class Main {
    let faceOverlayArray: [String]
    var faceOverlayContent: SCNNode
    init(faceOverlayArray:[String],faceOverlayContent:SCNNode) {
    self.faceOverlayArray = ["overlayModelBlack", "overlayModelBlue", "overlayModelRed", "overlayModelGreen", "overlayModelWhite"]
    self.faceOverlayContent = loadedContentForAsset(named: faceOverlayArray1[0])
    }
}
let faceOverlayArray1 = ["overlayModelBlack", "overlayModelBlue", "overlayModelRed", "overlayModelGreen", "overlayModelWhite"]`
```

This is the didSwipe() method that I am attempting to use to cycle through the array (it continues to return the same index)

```
public   func didSwipeRight() -> String {
    let arrayLength = faceOverlayArray1.count
    var index = 0
    index = (index < arrayLength) ? index+1 : 0
        print(index)
    var faceOverlayContent = faceOverlayArray1[index]
    return faceOverlayContent
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do when typing `let faceOverlayArray1 = (faceOverlayArray: ["overlayModelBlack", "overlayModelBlue", "overlayModelRed", "overlayModelGreen", "overlayModelWhite"]) as! [String]`?

Comment: I was attempting to create an instance of faceOverlayArray; realized that was entirely unnecessary and I could just declare it directly faceOverlayArray1 = [String].

Comment: Saying "instance of faceOverlayArray" is incorrect :) `faceOverlayArray` is just a property in the `Main` class. Are you aiming to create an instance of `Main` with value for its `faceOverlayArray` array?

Comment: My "greenness" is clearly showing. This is what I have changed the code to; it seems to be doing what I want. (Included separately below). However, I seem unable to change value of faceOverlayContent by moving through it using the UISwipeGesture Recognizer.

Comment: You are using a local `index` variable in your function, so each time the function is called it will be initialised to 0. You want to store your `index` in an instance property. Also, while a global will work for your array, using globals isn't best practice.

Comment: Got it. Thank you